# Pass a php object through json

Tags: php, json, class

**Problem statement:**

I have to pass a php object from one php application to another using json. In my destination application, I am not able to access my member functions after json_decode.

Here is the sample script:

```
<?php
class TestScope{
        private $privateVar;
        function __construct(){
                $this->privateVar="private";
        }
        function getPrivateVar(){
                return $this->privateVar;
        }
}
$testScope = new TestScope();
$encode = json_encode($testScope);
$decode = json_decode($encode);
print_r($decode->getPrivateVar());
?>
```

After executing the script, I am getting below error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::getPrivateVar()
```

What is the possible solution to prevent this error?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397758/json-decode-to-custom-class

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was serializing and un-serializing the object(s) before putting them in cookies, sessions or databases.

I suppose it will work for this problem aswell:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php