# How to loop through array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I'm very new to PHP and I need your help! 
I need to write backend for my app that receives json post and write data to json file. And I'm stuck with looping through array.

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postData);
var_damp($request)
```

shows array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Alex Jordan"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "alex@gmail.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    int(123456789)
    ["street"]=>
    string(12) "street, str."
    ["city"]=>
    string(7) "Chicago"
    ["state"]=>
    string(7) "Chicago"
    ["zip"]=>
    string(5) "07202"
    ["$$hashKey"]=>
    string(8) "object:3"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "Michael Jonhson"
    ["email"]=>
    string(17) "michael@gmail.com"
    ["phone"]=>
    float(11987654321)
    ["street"]=>
    string(12) "street, str."
    ["city"]=>
    string(11) "Los Angeles"
   ["state"]=>
   string(10) "California"
   ["zip"]=>
   string(5) "27222"
   ["$$hashKey"]=>
   string(8) "object:4"
 }
}
```

I'm trying to loop through the objects and getting error

`Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
    foreach($request as $i => $i_value) {
        echo $i_value;
    }
```

Comment: `echo $i_value->name;` etc... Or foreach the object as well.

Answer (score 13):

`$i_value` *is* the object. Because it's an object you cannot just echo it (unlike in JavaScript where you can cast any object to string).

You can echo specific properties of the object:

```
foreach($request as $i => $i_value) {
    echo $i_value->name;
}
```

Of course you could also use `var_dump` again to dump each object. `print_r` should work too.

Objects can only be casted to string like you do if they implement the [`__toString()` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring), but the objects created by `json_decode` are just simple `StdClass` objects that do not implement this. It's probably not your intention to do this at all, but if you're curious, you may have a look at [json_decode to custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397758/json-decode-to-custom-class) to see how you may use a custom class instead of StdClass.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. I used a `for` loop to loop through the array which gave me an error of `undefined offset`. Using `isset()` solved the error of `undefined offset`. I know its too late to answer this question but here it is for someone who might be looking for it in future

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postData);
// or you can do $postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$arrayOfUsers = $request->data; // I used a key of data while sending the array via fetch API

for($x = 0; $x < count($arrayOfUsers); $x++)
{
    if(isset($arrayOfUsers[$x]))
    {
        $name = $arrayOfUsers[$x]->name;
        $email = $arrayOfUsers[$x]->email;
        $phone = $arrayOfUsers[$x]->phone;
        $street = $arrayOfUSers[$x]->street;
        // .... and so on
       // then you can do whatever you want with the data
    } else {
      echo "No Data Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [array_map(?callable $callback, array $array, array ...$arrays): array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map)

1. to get required properties of each object;
2. or even alter its data.

This code covers both cases ([sandbox_url](https://onlinephp.io/c/71d1c)):

```
<?php
$arr_of_objects[] = (object)['field_name' => 'test2', 'id' => 2];
$arr_of_objects[] = (object)['field_name' => 'test', 'id' => 1];

$array_of_names = array_map(function ($el) {
    return $el->field_name;
}, $arr_of_objects);

echo 'get field_name from array of objects' . "\n";
var_dump($array_of_names);

$replace_data_with = [
    1 => ['field_name' => 'replaced_name_1', 'id' => 777],
    2 => ['field_name' => 'replaced_name_2', 'id' => 999]
];

$changed_values = array_map(function ($el) use ($replace_data_with) {
    $el->field_name = $replace_data_with[$el->id]['field_name'];
    $el->id = $replace_data_with[$el->id]['id'];
    return $el;
}, $arr_of_objects);

echo 'alter data of each object' . "\n";
var_dump($changed_values);
```

Base array of Objects:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(5) "test2"
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
get field_name from array of objects
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
alter data of each object
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(15) "replaced_name_2"
    ["id"]=>
    int(999)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["field_name"]=>
    string(15) "replaced_name_1"
    ["id"]=>
    int(777)
  }
}
```