# PHP looping though array of object and selecting a field

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

So I am a little stuck here I have the followng array of objects

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ord_obj_guid] => b0c6836a-be91-e3b9-6083-685862edf6a0
            [job_type_obj_guid] => 9852c71f-e367-1ee0-ae05-ec5d1ee59661
            [client_sku] => 6215
            [client_description] => iSeamless Delivery and Hookup Add-On
            [ord_skus_guid] => 9828a5b5-8ea2-73a9-7f6e-622608f353c0
            [Current_Line_Item_Status] => 9828a5b5-8ea2-73a9-7f6e-622608f353c0
            [Product_Or_Service] => false
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ord_obj_guid] => b0c6836a-be91-e3b9-6083-685862edf6a0
            [job_type_obj_guid] => 48bdc72d-2d79-01dd-8991-1ff4d1d36021
            [client_sku] => 9410101
            [client_description] => HAULAWAY AND RECYCLING
            [ord_skus_guid] => dc58110d-afc4-b2b2-f02f-85c66700778a
            [Current_Line_Item_Status] => dc58110d-afc4-b2b2-f02f-85c66700778a
            [Product_Or_Service] => false
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ord_obj_guid] => b0c6836a-be91-e3b9-6083-685862edf6a0
            [job_type_obj_guid] => 09577d07-74df-6196-f050-3c08a1bcf77e
            [client_sku] => 3006
            [client_description] => Product Return
            [ord_skus_guid] => 3e9d1b73-566c-c4d3-1dfa-4bef21cdc2ad
            [Current_Line_Item_Status] => 3e9d1b73-566c-c4d3-1dfa-4bef21cdc2ad
            [Product_Or_Service] => true
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ord_obj_guid] => b0c6836a-be91-e3b9-6083-685862edf6a0
            [job_type_obj_guid] => ff7a9a7f-5120-a089-ac0e-67d83c10533e
            [client_sku] => 3005
            [client_description] => Product Delivery
            [ord_skus_guid] => 8142eee9-fe83-74d8-958e-97439d6dd6ca
            [Current_Line_Item_Status] => 8142eee9-fe83-74d8-958e-97439d6dd6ca
            [Product_Or_Service] => true
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ord_obj_guid] => b0c6836a-be91-e3b9-6083-685862edf6a0
            [job_type_obj_guid] => 5d64cd87-6ccd-adf7-1015-a6e21710541c
            [client_sku] => 4001225
            [client_description] => INSTALL COOK TOP
            [ord_skus_guid] => 2b60db24-8130-14c4-fb3e-5b42033d1909
            [Current_Line_Item_Status] => 2b60db24-8130-14c4-fb3e-5b42033d1909
            [Product_Or_Service] => false
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ord_obj_guid] => b0c6836a-be91-e3b9-6083-685862edf6a0
            [job_type_obj_guid] => 48bdc72d-2d79-01dd-8991-1ff4d1d36021
            [client_sku] => 9410101
            [client_description] => HAULAWAY AND RECYCLING
            [ord_skus_guid] => 4e884ae1-eb59-4d4b-4d4c-211b23d56f89
            [Current_Line_Item_Status] => 4e884ae1-eb59-4d4b-4d4c-211b23d56f89
            [Product_Or_Service] => false
        )

)
```

I want to loop though it, and then if the Product or Service field is true I want to call a function, I am taking I need a foreach loop but I am little lost on how I should set the foreach loop up, any help would be greatly appericted

Comment: The function you are calling on true, is return something ??

Comment: You have showed your input data, that's step one.  Step 2 and 3 are showing your coding attempt, and showing your desired result.

Comment: Who ever upvoted this question -- realize that this is "not a well researched question" and is not deserving of an upvote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through array of objects in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753453/how-to-loop-through-array-of-objects-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   //$param = array();
$param = array(
    array("ord_obj_guid"=>80,"job_type_obj_guid"=>89,"client_sku"=>79,"client_description"=>80,"ord_skus_guid"=>79,"Current_Line_Item_Status"=>79,"Product_Or_Service"=>false),
    array("ord_obj_guid"=>80,"job_type_obj_guid"=>89,"client_sku"=>79,"client_description"=>80,"ord_skus_guid"=>79,"Current_Line_Item_Status"=>79,"Product_Or_Service"=>true),
    array("ord_obj_guid"=>80,"job_type_obj_guid"=>89,"client_sku"=>79,"client_description"=>80,"ord_skus_guid"=>79,"Current_Line_Item_Status"=>79,"Product_Or_Service"=>false),
  array("ord_obj_guid"=>80,"job_type_obj_guid"=>89,"client_sku"=>79,"client_description"=>80,"ord_skus_guid"=>79,"Current_Line_Item_Status"=>79,"Product_Or_Service"=>false),
);

for($i=0;$i<count($param);$i++){
  if($param[$i]['Product_Or_Service']=='true'){
      echo "Done";
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```