# Convert json String into Object of custom class instead of stdClass.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

my **order.php** file has

```
 /**
 * Encode the cart items from json to object
 * @param $value
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCartItemsAttribute($value){
   return json_decode($value);
}
```

And in my controller i fetch cartItems as follows

```
public function orderDetails(Order $order){

   $address = implode(',',array_slice((array)$order->address,2,4));

foreach ($order->cartItems as $item){
    dd($item);
       }
   return view('/admin/pages/productOrders/orderDetails',compact('order','address'));


}
```

And in above code **dd($item)** will outputs as follows

```
   {#422 ▼
  +"id": 4
  +"user_id": 2
  +"product_id": 1
  +"quantity": 1
  +"deleted_at": null
  +"created_at": "2018-02-16 08:12:08"
  +"updated_at": "2018-02-16 08:12:08"
}
```

but I want as below.

```
   Cart {#422 ▼
  +"id": 4
  +"user_id": 2
  +"product_id": 1
  +"quantity": 1
  +"deleted_at": null
  +"created_at": "2018-02-16 08:12:08"
  +"updated_at": "2018-02-16 08:12:08"
}
```

How can i achieve this in laravel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode to custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397758/json-decode-to-custom-class)

Answer (score 1):

Add `true` as a second parameter to your decode function like:

```
/**
 * Decode the cart items from json to an associative array.
 *
 * @param $value
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCartItemsAttribute($value){
   return json_decode($value, true);
}
```

I would create a `CartItem` model:

```
// CartItem.php
class CartItem extends Model {
   public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
   }
}
```

Instantiate each one like:

```
// Controller.php
$cartItems = [];
foreach ($order->cartItems as $item){
    // using json_encode and json_decode will give you an associative array of attributes for the model.
    $attributes = json_decode(json_encode($item), true);
    $cartItems[] = new CartItem($attributes);

    // alternatively, use Eloquent's create method
    CartItem::create(array_merge($attributes, [
        'order_id' => $order->id
    ]);
}
```