# Array inside array to Object

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, object

after using this code to send params through ajax:

```
 paramsToSend = $form.serializeArray();
 params = JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)
```

I got this array after decode json on serverside:

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [name] => name
        [value] => Naomi
      )

    [1] => Array
      (
        [name]  => password
        [value] => test123456
      )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => email
        [value] => naomitest@gmail.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => code
        [value] => test123456@test123456
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name]  => phone
        [value] => 423523545435
    )

)
```

1. Can I convert it to Object and get value like this:

   ```
   User.name //will print Naomi
   User.password // will print test123456
   ```

Because I need other different params for ajax call, is the way I serializeArray data + convert to json best practices? If not please give me advice. Thanks

Comment: Convert to object where? On PHP side? If yes,check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397758/json-decode-to-custom-class

Comment: You can iterate though it and build an Object, no?

Comment: where do you want to execute the `User.password`? on javascript or server?

Comment: @ariefbayu, I want to get the data on the server, it does not necessary an object but I found it easy to get value by key than keeping it as array and have a hard time to loop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this one you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to pull out the keys and values, then [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to combine them into a key/value array, then use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) to make it an array or object.

**For example:**

```
<?php
$data = [
    ['name' => 'name', 'value' => 'Naomi'],
    ['name' => 'password', 'value' => 'test123456'],
    ['name' => 'email', 'value' => 'naomitest@gmail.com'],
    ['name' => 'code', 'value' => 'test123456@test123456'],
    ['name' => 'phone', 'value' => 423523545435]
];

$data = new ArrayObject(
    array_combine(
        array_column($data, 'name'),
        array_column($data, 'value')
    )
);
$data->setFlags(ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST|ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);

echo $data->name; // Naomi
echo $data['name']; // Naomi
```

https://3v4l.org/oBbd0