# How to create constructor with optional parameters?

Tags: php, function, oop

I have __construct($parameter)

```
public function __construct($nick) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE nick='".$nick."'";
    $result = App::runQuery($query);
    $user = $result->fetch_object();

    $this->id = $user->id;
    $this->nick = $user->nick;
    $this->email = $user->email;
    $this->password = $user->password;
    $this->birthDay = $user->birthDay;
    $this->sex = $user->sex;
    $this->about = $user->about;
    $this->city = $user->city;
    $this->photo = $user->photo;
    $this->following = $user->following;
    $this->followers = $user->followers;
    $this->statu = $user->statu; 

}
```

And now I want to have a default constructor without parameters like this:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this->id = NULL;
    $this->nick = NULL;
    $this->email = NULL;
    $this->password = NULL;
    $this->birthDay = NULL;
    $this->sex = NULL;
    $this->about = NULL;
    $this->city = NULL;
    $this->photo = NULL;
    $this->following = NULL;
    $this->followers = NULL;
    $this->statu = NULL; 

}
```

But something is wrong and I get error like this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare User::__construct() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxx/Application/User.php on line 33
```

How can I have two constructors with parameters and without parameters at the same time?

Comment: While you're probably not working on this two years later you have an obvious SQL injection bug in this code

Answer (score -11, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answer. I have solved the problem with my way.

```
public function __construct($nick) {
    if($nick != NULL) {//for user 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE nick='".$nick."'";
        $result = App::runQuery($query);
        $user = $result->fetch_object();

        $this->id = $user->id;
        $this->nick = $user->nick;
        $this->email = $user->email;
        $this->password = $user->password;
        $this->birthDay = $user->birthDay;
        $this->sex = $user->sex;
        $this->about = $user->about;
        $this->city = $user->city;
        $this->photo = $user->photo;
        $this->following = $user->following;
        $this->followers = $user->followers;
        $this->statu = $user->statu; 
    }else {//for null
        $this->id = NULL;
        $this->nick = NULL;
        $this->email = NULL;
        $this->password = NULL;
        $this->birthDay = NULL;
        $this->sex = NULL;
        $this->about = NULL;
        $this->city = NULL;
        $this->photo = NULL;
        $this->following = NULL;
        $this->followers = NULL;
        $this->statu = NULL;
    }

}
```

It works!

Comment: I think this is not a good implementation

Comment: I think you missed the actual point of argument being optional which was addressed by @TimCooper here is the clue `public function __construct($nick = null)`

Comment: With PHP > 7.4  it should be `public function __construct($nick = null)`.

Comment: You code works because it only has one param.
Also the else part can be omit, because it is the default value of the attributes.
For a constructor which needs either zero or multiple params I could only think of handling this using an array. Then I could check if the param is an array and if so check the number of entries in the array.

Answer (score 22):

1. There is no overloading in PHP; you cannot have methods with the same names but different parameters
2. Since all of your properties will default to null, there's no reason to do it yourself. I would suggest doing the following:

   ```
   public function __construct($nick = null) {
       if ($nick != null) {
           $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE nick='".$nick."'";
           $result = App::runQuery($query);
           $user = $result->fetch_object();

           $this->id = $user->id;
           $this->nick = $user->nick;
           $this->email = $user->email;
           $this->password = $user->password;
           $this->birthDay = $user->birthDay;
           $this->sex = $user->sex;
           $this->about = $user->about;
           $this->city = $user->city;
           $this->photo = $user->photo;
           $this->following = $user->following;
           $this->followers = $user->followers;
           $this->statu = $user->statu; 
       }
   }
   ```
3. An alternative to the above code is to have multiple, static constructor methods, and use a private constructor:

   ```
   private function __construct() {
   }

   public static function createFromNick($nick) {
       $self = new self();

       $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE nick='".$nick."'";
       $result = App::runQuery($query);
       $user = $result->fetch_object();

       $self->id = $user->id;
       $self->nick = $user->nick;
       $self->email = $user->email;
       $self->password = $user->password;
       $self->birthDay = $user->birthDay;
       $self->sex = $user->sex;
       $self->about = $user->about;
       $self->city = $user->city;
       $self->photo = $user->photo;
       $self->following = $user->following;
       $self->followers = $user->followers;
       $self->statu = $user->statu;

       return $self;
   }

   public static function createEmpty() {
       return new self();
   }
   ```

Comment: Note that in PHP constructors are not allowed to throw any `Throwable`s such as `Exception`s.  It will just crash the execution of the PHP script. Usually database queries in PHP are allowed to throw `Exception`s. But I'm not sure what this App:: thing is in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct() {
    // allocate your stuff
}

public static function withRow( array $row ) {
    $instance = new self();
    $instance->fill( $row );
    return $instance;
}

protected function fill( array $row ) {
    // fill all properties from array
}
```

For details check this answer : [Best way to do multiple constructors in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699796/best-way-to-do-multiple-constructors-in-php)