# Optional argument in a class method with $this in PHP

Tags: php, class, methods, parameters

I have a question close to this:

> [How to create constructor with optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395855/how-to-create-constructor-with-optional-parameters)

It is clear that we can make optional params like this:

```
function myFunction($param='hello')
```

but I want to use it in a class's method with `$this->something` instead of 'hello', it looks like this:

```
public function myFunction($param=$this->property)
```

but I get a:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this'
```

Is it possible to get it?

Comment: Set it to null, then if its null set it to your property within the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set to null and check afterward

```
 class example {
 private $something = "something";
 public function myFunction($a = null) 
 {
    if($a === null) 
       $a = $this->something; 
     // more code goes here
    return $a; 
  }
 }
 $test = new example();
 print $test->myFunction();
 // prints "something"
 print $test->myFunction("hello");
 // prints "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$Obj = new myclass();
class myclass{

    var $data = 'tested';
    function __construct(){
        $this->testFunction();
    }

    public function testFunction($param = null){
        if( $param == '' || $param == null){
            $param = $this->data;
        }
        echo $param;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think putting 
if($param=== null)
would be better than
if($param=='' OR $param ==null)
because a '' may be a valid value in my case, anyway thank you a lot.