# In CQ(R)S, is it OK to use a Command as a parameter of a model constructor?

Tags: cqrs, command-query-separation

Say I have a `CreateUser` command:

```php
class CreateUser
{
    public string $email;
    public string $password;
    public string $firstName;
    public string $lastName;
    public LocalDate $dateOfBirth;
    public ?string $location;
}
```

Is it OK if my `User` model accepts this command as a constructor parameter?

i.e. instead of having this:

```php
class User
{
    public function __construct(
        string $email,
        string $password,
        string $firstName,
        string $lastName,
        LocalDate $dateOfBirth,
        ?string $location
    ) {
       ...
```

and have the command handler map the command data to the model(s), I could just simply make the model constructors accept the command as a parameter and extract the data they need:

```php
class User
{
    public function __construct(CreateUser $command)
    {
        ...
}
```

Is this a correct approach, or are there drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a correct approach, or are there drawbacks?

Small drawbacks.

Drawback #1 - you've added a (small) extra step of work.  If I want a User, I first have to get a CreateUser command.  So there's an extra step that gets in the way.

Drawback #2 - because you need a CreateUser, you need values for all of the fields of User *and* all of the extra fields that User doesn't care about.

For example, suppose you later decide that `CreateUser` should have a messageId.  Now the code paths that want a User need to invent a messageId that they don't want in order to construct a CreateUser that they don't want so that they can construct the User that they do want.

Wanting to have a function that accepts a CreateUser and returns a User is perfectly reasonable.  It's even reasonable that you would want that function to be close to User.

You probably don't want that function to be __construct, though.  A [static helper method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701337/54734) would probably be a healthier long term solution.