# php inheritance constructor with parameters

Tags: php

I have problem with my class.

I have main class Action:

```
abstract class Action
{
    function __construct(tszka &$szk, Zdarzenie $zdarz, array $parametry=[]){
        $this->szk = $szk;
        $this->zdarz = $zdarz;
        $this->parametry = $parametry;
    }
}
```

and child class:

```
class ChangeStatus extends Akcja
{

    public $tryb;
    public $status;
    public $czynnosc;

    function __construct(){
        $this->tryb = 'special;
        $this->status = 1;
        $this->czynnosc = 'make;
        
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

In ChangeStatus class i have error in constructor:
Too few arguments to function Action::__construct(), 0 passed in ChangeStatus.php.

How can i repair it?

Please help me :)
I am beginner

Comment: What is `Akcja`?  The base class shown above is called `Action`.  You also have a syntax error  in the constructor for `ChangeStatus`.  Please include an actual [mcve], not just text that might kind of look like the code you're referring to.

Comment: @David "Akcja" is just Polish for Action.

Comment: @Olivier: I would imagine so, but PHP doesn't know that and isn't going to make that translation.  For the clarity of the question and for future readers, the OP should provide code which demonstrates the problem.  Currently that problem is obscured by multiple other problems in this code.

Answer (score 0):

The base class' constructor expects **3** parameters:

```
function __construct(tszka &$szk, Zdarzenie $zdarz, array $parametry=[])
```

The derived class is passing it **0** parameters:

```
parent::__construct();
```

It's not clear to me what values *should* be provided, but you'd need to provide some values when constructing an instance of the class:

```
parent::__construct($someTszka, $someZdarz, $someArray);
```

Alternatively, if the derived class shouldn't/can't provide any values to the base class, you can update the base class' constructor to not require any:

```
abstract class Action
{
  function __construct() {
  }
}
```

Or perhaps you want some mix of the two, in some way emulating the functionality of [multiple constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1699796/328193).  Any way you structure it, when constructing an instance of a class you need to provide the values required by the constructor of that class.