PHP inheritance with inherited properties
I'd like to have the following class configuration.
class Parent
{
    protected ParentMapperInterface $mapper;

    public function __construct(ParentMapperInterface $mapper)
    {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }
    
    // other methods that I would like to be available to all children
}

class Child1 extends Parent
{
    protected Child1MapperInterface $mapper
    
    public function __construct(Child1MapperInterface $childMapper, // some other arguments)
    {
        $this->mapper = $childMapper;
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent
{
    protected Child2MapperInterface $mapper
    
    public function __construct(Child2MapperInterface $childMapper, // some other arguments)
    {
        $this->mapper = $childMapper;
    }
}
// other children

Child1 extends Parent and has its Child1Mapper under $mapper property. The same is for Child2.
Child1Mapper, Child2Mapper extend ParentMapper. I made such class configuration because Child1, Child2, etc. share
same methods as Parent, and Child1Mapper, Child2Mapper, etc. share some methods of ParentMapper.
The problem is that with this configuration I get a PHP error that signatures of __construct methods of Parent
and Child should be the same.
Any idea how to get what I want?

The child classes don't need their own __construct() methods. The inherited constructor will fill in the $mapper property, which is also inherited.

@Barmar, the problem is that the Child __construct have other input arguments, sorry I didn't mention it in the first place. updated the question.

I think the general recommendation is to use other methods instead of constructors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699796/best-way-to-do-multiple-constructors-in-php

I would make the constructor in the extended class call the parent constructor. And you need only one $mapper property:
interface ParentMapperInterface
{
}

interface ChildMapperInterface extends ParentMapperInterface
{
}

class ChildMapper implements ChildMapperInterface
{
}

class ParentClass
{
    protected ParentMapperInterface $mapper;

    public function __construct(ParentMapperInterface $mapper)
    {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    protected int $other;

    public function __construct(ChildMapperInterface $mapper, int $other)
    {
        parent::__construct($mapper);
        $this->other = $other;
    }
}

$obj = new ChildClass(new ChildMapper(), 0);

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4AGfp
