# Creating new node keeps changing all nodes (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, nodes, avl-tree

I am trying to build an AVL tree, but seem to be having a problem with nodes. I try to make a new node and it changes all the values of other nodes to whatever I was giving the new node.

```
//AVL.java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AVL{
    static AvlNode root;

   public static void tree(int[] list){
      for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
         insertPrep(list[i]);
      }
   }


   public static void insertPrep(int data){
        //if not null insert data into existing root node otherwise make new node using data
        if (root==null){root = new AvlNode(data);}
        else {
             System.out.println("inPr else");
             System.out.println(root.key +  " & " + data);
             AvlNode newNode = new AvlNode(data);
             System.out.println(root.key +  " & " + newNode.key);

      }
    }

   //where tree is made and stored
    static class AvlNode{
        static int key, height; //data for input numbers and height for height of nodes to keep balance
        static AvlNode left, right; //left for left side of tree and right for right side of tree    

        AvlNode(int data){
             key = data;
       }

   }
}
```

And here is what I am using the above for:
    //Tree.java
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Tree{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      int n = 10; //numbers to be in array
      int a[] = new int[n]; //first array

      for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
         a[i] = i+1; //insert #'s 1-n; smallest to largest

      }

      AVL.tree(a); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the `static` modifier means and how it affects class attributes?

Comment: also you are not connecting root to any node in else part

Comment: `AvlNode`'s fields should not be static.

Comment: Not really. I just know the compiler was mad at me before because things weren't made static.

Comment: Right.  Gotta watch those emotional compilers :-).  Static means that something doesn't belong to a particular instance of a class.  To use non-static methods or fields, you need to create an object.  Doing that would have been a better idea than making everything static.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In laymans terms, what does 'static' mean in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649213/in-laymans-terms-what-does-static-mean-in-java)

Comment: Don't change things to make your code compile without knowing why you're changing it. Googling the error should give you a decent idea of the problem, if not, we'd happily help by explaining why you're getting the error and the steps required to fix it.

Comment: "I try to make a new node and it changes all the values of other nodes to whatever I was giving the new node." It looks like you *do* know what static means  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being rather brief with my earlier comment.  Your problem is these two lines inside `AvlNode`.

```
static int key, height; 
static AvlNode left, right;
```

That implies that every `AvlNode` has the same value, for each of these four fields.  That would mean that there's only one `key`, and one `height` for every node of the tree; and only one left descendant and only one right descendant of every node of the tree.  You really need to remove those `static` modifiers, so that every `AvlNode` instance can have its own copies of these four fields.