# what does the error statement define in the case of main method Overloading

Tags: java

```
public class Sample{
     public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("/n Say hi 2 me");
        }

public class Hello{
      public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("/n Hello!");
         }
      }
   }
```

I have run this code using Command Prompt but I was able to notice that **modifier 'static' is used for only constant variable Declarations** 
why?????
please help me out in understanding this???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649213/in-laymans-terms-what-does-static-mean-in-java

Comment: whats the question... you want to understand what static does in main function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

main method with single String[] (or) String... as param will be considered as entry point for the program.

So we cant have two completely same main methods in one java class

you can have other method named main but it should have different parameters(overloading of method)

Answer (score 0):

static can be used with variables as well as methods but can't be used for a class
   static variables are initialized before the object creation when the class is loaded and static
   methods can be called before object creation as well