# Static problems when calling 'this' in a repeating task

Tags: java, static, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a plugin that uses a `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` and the task is created by calling a method. The problem is trying to call it from a different class.

When I try to call the method, it will say that the method needs to be `static`. So, I make the method `static` and then the first parameter in the `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` says it cannot be used in a `static` context.

**My Method**

```
public static void newCountdown() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Player player : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
                player.sendMessage("Hey");
            }
        }                   
    }, 0, 20);
}
```

I'm kind of new to Java at the minute and `static` variables are still something I'm trying to understand so if anyone can link me to somewhere I can read up on it, or even a video then that would be great.

As for the problem, if anyone has the solution then any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 'this' is a reference to an object to which you do not have access from static (ie. class) method. Class methods know nothing about particular instances.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649213/in-laymans-terms-what-does-static-mean-in-java) to get a quick and easy explanation of the `static` keyword.

To avoid the error saying the method needs to be static call the method on an instance rather than the class.

Like this:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.newCountdown();
```

instead of:

```
Foo.newCountdown();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I have used this in another plugin that I have made  and It works fine. The Plugin I'm doing now though doesn't seem to let it work and I think it might have something to do with the class being in a different package. Could this be the case?

Comment: The package wouldn't matter. Did you try removing `static` from your method signature and calling the method on an instance of your class?

Comment: Yes, the method is not static but when I use the bit to call an instance instead of the class, that is the part that gives me the error in console.. No matter where I put it, as soon as it executes that line of code it dies.

Comment: The error is too long for a comment so I have uploaded it to 
http://pastebin.com/E8iDZPAT

Comment: I don't have any experience with bukkit but I found [this thread](https://bukkit.org/threads/plugin-already-initialized.322695/) which I hope helps.

Comment: Hey, so that thread you linked sort of helped. Basically the problem now is if I do `static package.Main main = new package.Main();`, this does not work unless I don't use static. Any Ideas?

Comment: Hey, could you take a look at my new question? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256521/calling-the-method-on-an-instance-rather-than-the-class-not-working-with-static

Answer (score 0):

Static methods refers to the class, not to a specific instance. They are common to all instances of the class.

You can call a static method without any instance and its why you can refer to *this* inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get access to this, on a static method. Please have a look here:
[Oracle Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)