# Why we need transient keyword to prevent serialization? [ Java ]

Tags: java

I do not understand that why we need transient keyword to prevent serialization of a particular data member. We can also make it static because static data member can not be serialized. Please guide me if I am wrong!

Comment: [Here's an explanation of `static`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649213/in-laymans-terms-what-does-static-mean-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` does not *just* make a member not serialized; it also means that there is only one copy of that field for the *entire class*.  If you want there to be a copy of that field for each object, but do not want that object to be serialized, you need `transient`; `static` will do something completely different.

Making variables `static` without fully understanding this is a massively common source of bugs for new Java developers.