# Difference in the number of count when count is static and non static in Java

Tags: java, static, non-static, members

I am trying this below program

```
class Car1
{
    static int count;
    Car1()
    {
        System.out.println("Car instance has been created...");
    }

    Car1(int arg) {
        System.out.println("Car instance has been created...");
    }

    Car1(double arg) {
        System.out.println("Car instance has been created...");
    }
    Car1(int arg1, double arg2) {
        System.out.println("Car instance has been crreated...");
    }
    {
        count++;
    }
}
public class MainClass10
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Program Started");
        new Car1(11);
        new Car1(11, 12.11);
        for (int i = 0; i<9; i++)
        {
            new Car1();
        }
        Car1 c1 = new Car1(11.12);
        System.out.println("Total number of cars: " + c1.count);
        System.out.println("Program Ended");
    }
}
```

The output for number of count is 12
and when I try this by changing count variable as non static then 'number of count is 1'.

Could anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: You can take a look at the answers of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static means the counter will be shared across all instance of the `Car1` class. 
On the other hand if you don't use a static counter, each instance of the Car class (each time you do a `new Car1(...)`) will have its own counter. It's not shared.
Hence you'll only be printing the counter of instance c1.

If you don't get it look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2649252/1722236) for another explanation.