# Can a static member refer/access to an instance method of a class?

Tags: java, static, instance, printstream

As far as i know it is not true then how come *out* variable of System class

```
 final static PrintStream out = null;
```

can refer to the *print* method of the PrintStream class in `System.out.print();`

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

PS: This question is not same as What's the meaning of System.out.println in Java? or any related one.

Comment: there is no relation between the two code snippets.

Comment: In System.out.print() or in system.out.println() methods out variable is used to refer to print method

Comment: you are mixing up all sorts of statements and terminology here. You *obviously* do not yet understand what System.out.println means / does.

Comment: out is an instance of PrintStream so it can use PrintStream’s instance methods.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what `static` means. You might want to see if one of the answers in [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413898) or [In laymans terms, what does 'static' mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2649213) answers your question, or read up about `static` further elsewhere.

Comment: out is having static keyword so isn't it a static variable of Printstream type?

Comment: out is a static member of the System class.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "static members cannot refer to instance methods" is an oversimplification that causes confusion.

The actual restriction is that static methods and static field initializers cannot invoke instance methods without providing a reference to a specific object for the invocation.

In case with `static System.out` there is no issue at all, because `print` is invoked directly on the `PrintStream` object, which happens to be stored as a `static` field of some *other* class, in this case, `java.lang.System`. There is no difference between

```
System.out.print("hello");
```

and

```
PrintStream myOutput = System.out;
myOutput.print("hello");
```