# I have Problem to understand what static keyword do (in java)

Tags: java

I'm new to java ,I can't understand what's the difference between static methods-variables and non-static method-variables ,Can you help me , Thank You Guys.

Comment: `static` - one per class (a global). not `static` - one per instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649213/in-laymans-terms-what-does-static-mean-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In laymans terms, what does 'static' mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649213/in-laymans-terms-what-does-static-mean-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-and-non-static-variables-in-java/) is a very good article, feel free to read it. You can think of static as simply meaning **a single copy**. Take the following example;

```
class A {

    private static int a;

    public A(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

}
```

Class A has a method called getA() that returns the value of a. Note that the variable a is static.

```java
A a1 = new A(0);

A a2 = new A(1);

a1.setA(2);
```

// both values would be 2 since a1 and a2 share the same single copy.

```java
int a1a = a1.getA();

int a2a = a2.getA();
```