# Using static vector as a storage

Tags: c++, vector, static

My program has a enum to store `colors` and `user response` like this. Now I need to keep `RGB` and `CYMK` values along with the color. So this cannot do using enum,

```
enum COLOR
{
    RED = 'R',
    GREEN = 'G',
    BLUE = 'B',
    YELLOW = 'Y',
    MAGENTA = 'M'
};
```

So I' planing to use static array of struct  for this purpose. I use static because

1. These values are never change in the program
2. To avoid multiple  creation of the vector when other classes creating and destroying this classes object.

   ```
   struct Color
   {
    char user_responce;
    std::string rgb_code;
    std::string cymk_code;
   };

   static std::vector<Color> colors;
   colors.push_back('R', "FF0000", "30 - 96 - 76 - 26");
   ```

   But after reading this post [Is using a lot of static methods a bad thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752758/is-using-a-lot-of-static-methods-a-bad-thing) I feel bad about the way I'm doing.
   Is this a  **"unsafe" statics**? any other suggestion?

Comment: What is the question?  You want an opinion or a better solution?

Comment: I feel like this is not a solid solution. So looking for a better solution

Comment: Reason 1 is not good enough for using Static.
Reason 2: Maybe you need a singleton pattern

Comment: also if you are making something static because "it doesnt change" then it should also be `const`.

Answer (score 2):

If the values never change then you can do this:

```
static const std::vector<Colour> colors = 
{   { 'R', "FFFF00", "blabla" }
,   { 'S', "00FF00", "foo" }
,   { 'T', "0f3033", "burnt sienna" }
};
```

Personally I would use a C-style array and pointers to char here; in general those are bad idea but for static variables it removes the risk of undefined behaviour due to accessing an object that has not had its constructor called yet.