# Which one of the below is a better programming practice in java to call methods present in a user defined class?

Tags: java

```
Stack newStack = new Stack();
newStack.push(0);
```

OR

```
Stack.push(0);
```

Note: Here Stack is a user defined class to implement concept of stack manually in java and not the predefined one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using a lot of static methods a bad thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752758/is-using-a-lot-of-static-methods-a-bad-thing) If not really, then search for more.

Comment: On the other hand, if the design of `Stack` is given and `push` *is*  a static method, then `Stack.push(0)` is clearly preferred as clearest and concisest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows having multiple stacks for different purposes.

```
Stack newStack = new Stack();
newStack.push(0);
```

We can have only one stack when using this.

```
Stack.push(0);
```

I prefer the first one as it allows initializing multiple stacks at the same time which the second way can't do.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `push` is a non-static method of the `Stack` class.  In order to use the `push` method, you have to create an instance of the `Stack` class.

```
Stack newStack = new Stack();
newStack.push(0);
```

The equivalent code with an anonymous instance would be:

```
new Stack().push(0);
```

which would be kind of useless in this case, since you're eventually going to want to `pop` the stack you created.

In the second example, `push` is a static method of the `Stack` class.

```
Stack.push(0);
```

Nandu Raj is correct in his answer in that you can only have one `Stack` in your application, rather than more than one with the non-static `push` method.

Creating and using non-static methods is generally a better programming practice, although there are cases, like the Java `Math` class, where static methods work better.